# Pyspark - Append new column to dataframe, by locating 'previous' record

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having a little trouble phrasing this question.

I've got a huge amount of event data that I'm in the process of attempting to clean. One of the requirements is to include data from a previous event and I'm struggling to find a suitable way of doing this using `pyspark`.

To try and illustrate. Assuming my data frame looks like this:

```
uid| id|          event_time| event_value|
---|---|--------------------|------------|
1  |  1| 2017-11-20 12:00:00|           a|
2  |  1| 2017-11-20 13:00:00|           b|
3  |  2| 2017-11-20 12:00:00|           c|
4  |  2| 2017-11-20 13:00:00|           d|
5  |  2| 2017-11-20 14:00:00|           e|
```

For each records, I want to find the most recent previous event with the same ID and append this as a new column. i.e.

```
uid| id|          event_time| event_value| previous_event_value|
---|---|--------------------|------------|---------------------|
1  |  1| 2017-11-20 12:00:00|           a|                 null|
2  |  1| 2017-11-20 13:00:00|           b|                    a|
3  |  2| 2017-11-20 12:00:00|           c|                 null|
4  |  2| 2017-11-20 13:00:00|           d|                    c|
5  |  2| 2017-11-20 14:00:00|           e|                    d|
```

I've look at some of the window functions, but I'm not 100% sure this supports my use case.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, use `lag` (window-functions)

Comment: While paritionin by id and ordering by uid and event_time ascending

Comment: Thanks both.  I've got something like this now which appears to be working...
`df = df.withColumn("previous_event_value", lag(df.event_value).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("event_time")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone else stumbles on this.  The suggestions above worked perfectly.  Using the lag window function. e.g.

```
df = df.withColumn("previous_event_value", 
  lag(df.event_value).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("e‌​vent_time")))
```